# Overload operator in template base class

Tags: c++, crtp

I've got the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define THIS(X) static_cast<X*>(this)

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
    }
    virtual ~Base() {
    }
    void foo() {
        THIS(T)->a[0] = 1;
    }
    T& operator=(const T& o) {
        std::cout <<"operator="<<std::endl;
        memcpy(THIS(T)->a, o.a, THIS(T)->size);
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Der1: public Base<Der1<T> > {
private:
    T* a;
    unsigned int size;
public:
    Der1(int d) {
        a = new T[d];
        size = d;
    }
    virtual ~Der1() {
        delete[] a;
    }
    using Base<Der1<T> >::operator=;
    friend class Base<Der1<T> > ;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int EL>
class Der2: public Base<Der2<T, EL> > {
private:
    T a[EL];
    unsigned int size;
public:
    Der2() {
        size = EL;
    }
    virtual ~Der2() {
    }
    using Base<Der2<T, EL> >::operator=;
    friend class Base<Der2<T, EL> > ;
};

int main() {
    Der1<double> a(5);
    Der2<double, 10> b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
    Der2<double, 10> c;
    Der1<double> d(5);
    c = b;
    a = d;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I receive this error:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../main.cpp:48:7: error: ‘constexpr Der2<double, 10>& Der2<double, 10>::operator=(const Der2<double, 10>&)’ cannot be overloaded
 class Der2: public Base<Der2<T, EL> > {
       ^~~~
../main.cpp:23:5: error: with ‘T& Base<T>::operator=(const T&) [with T = Der2<double, 10>]’
  T& operator=(const T& o) {
     ^~~~~~~~
../main.cpp:31:7: error: ‘constexpr Der1<double>& Der1<double>::operator=(const Der1<double>&)’ cannot be overloaded
 class Der1: public Base<Der1<T> > {
       ^~~~
../main.cpp:23:5: error: with ‘T& Base<T>::operator=(const T&) [with T = Der1<double>]’
  T& operator=(const T& o) {
     ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [subdir.mk:20: main.o] Error 1
```

If I use the keyword `virtual` in template base class `operator=` then it compiles but I can't see any output, so I'm not calling the right method.

Comment: There's always a copy assignment operator in a class. If you don't define one, the implementation will (possibly `delete`d). An operator you bring in with `using` doesn't count as defined in your class. g++ seems to be incorrect here as parent's assignment brought in with `using` is hidden, at least according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)). However you cannot exploit `using` here in any case.

Comment: This entire enterprise looks rather fishy to me. Why do you need CRTP here at all? Use `std::array` and `std::vector` and you shoud be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, clang accepts your code. This works in both, gcc and clang:

```
Base& operator=(const Base& o) {
    std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl;
    memcpy(self().a, o.self().a, self().size);
    return *this;
}

T& self() {
    return static_cast<T&>(*this);
}

const T& self() const {
    return static_cast<const T&>(*this);
}
```

BTW, a `virtual` destructor looks odd here: you're mixing compile-time polymorphism (via CRTP) with run-time polymorphism (via `virtual`). Probably, you don't need it.

**Edit.**

As @n.m. judiciously pointed in the comment, although this code compiles, it's broken because default-generated copy assignment operator is still there. So, in the derived class we should define copy assignment explicitly:

```
Der& operator=(const Der& o)
{
    Base<Der...>::operator=(o);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: are you talking about virtual destructor of base class? I think you are right

Comment: @greywolf82, yes. There is no point in making base class destructor virtual.

Comment: can you explain why this code works? I mean: the method returns base class but it's assigned to a derivative class so I was expecting a compilation error

Comment: @greywolf82, `a = b` is a syntactic sugar for `a.operator=(b)`, so the point of returning `*this` from `operator=` is to use chaining: `a = b = c` - in this expression you assign the result of `b.operator=(c)` to `a`. The value returned by `operator=` in your code is discarded, it can even return `void` if you don't need chaining.

Comment: @greywolf82, you can make it `T& operator=` and return `self()` if necessary. And there is no need for `using Base::operator=`.

Comment: This compiles and runs but does it really work in any real sense of the word? The `a` member is copied twice, once in child's assignment and once in parent's.