# Copy assignment operator in CRTP - gcc vs clang and msvc

Tags: c++, using, crtp

The following code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803895/overload-operator-in-template-base-class)) results in an error when compiled by gcc 8.2, but is accepted by clang 7.0.0 and msvc 15.9.0 preview 3:

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    void operator=(const T&) { }
    void foo() { }
};

struct D : public B<D>
{
    using B<D>::operator=;
    using B<D>::foo;       // hidden by D::foo
    void foo() { }
};

int main()
{
    D d1, d2;
    d1 = d2;
    d1.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message [generated by gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/cNx-GB) is:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'int main()':
> <source>:8:8: error: 'constexpr D& D::operator=(const D&)' cannot be overloaded with 'void B<T>::operator=(const T&) [with T = D]'
> struct D : public B<D>
>        ^
> <source>:4:8: note: previous declaration 'void B<T>::operator=(const T&) [with T = D]'
>   void operator=(const T&) { }
>        ^~~~~~~~
> ```

We have two assignment operators in `D`, the first one is the default-generated, the second one is introduced with `using`. They have the same signature, so the overloading fails. But why is `operator=` from the base class simply not hidden by the one in the derived, as it happens for the `foo()` member function?

What is going on here? Why only gcc complains? Should it complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is wrong here: this is [specially called out](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#4) as a situation where no overloading occurs.  (Neither does it happen for other member functions, of course, as you said.)